# Count the intersection of buffers, in the same layer. qgis

Tags: qgis, count, self-intersection

If I have one shape of buffers, How to count the number of times, the different buffers (in the same layer) intersect each other.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: given that this question asks about intersects, and the other question asks about overlap -- geometrically speaking, are they related?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location

And make the buffer both the "Target vector layer" and the "Join vector layer".
Place a checkmark beside "intersects" under "Geometric predicate". Press Run.

[image: join attributes by location in qgis]

You can probably erase the entries under "Statistics for summary" if none are needed.

This will output a new dataset with a [count] field. But one additional step is needed.

Create a new field called [overlaps] or something. Then in an edit session use the field calculator to something like: `"count"  - 1`

You will need to subtract 1 from the [count] field because it counted an additional intersect/overlap because of the identical buffer.

---

Another option, maybe simpler is to try and use "overlaps" instead of "intersects" and that means you don't have to create any additional fields. The count field should be correct as is.